# Add column value to proceeding rows until a new column value

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have to work with csv that has the following format

```
Foo
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
value1,value2,value3,value4
value1,value2,value3,value4
Bar
value1,value2,value3,value4
value1,value2,value3,value4
...
```

When I use pandas `read_csv` function, this file is read in as a single column csv. The number of rows between `Foo`, `Bar` and several other values is not consistent.

The desired output should take the form

```
    newCol,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
    Foo,value1,value2,value3,value4
    Foo,value1,value2,value3,value4
    Bar,value1,value2,value3,value4
    Bar,value1,value2,value3,value4
```

When I try `my_dataframe.stack()` it inserts `Foo` into each row and `Bar` and all other values are omitted. Is there a way using pandas or even just some regex approach to get what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by a simple approach:

```
with open("your_file") as f:
    my_val = ""
    header = ""
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        line = line.split(",")
        if len(line)==1:
            my_val = line[0]
        elif i==1:
            header = "newCol," + ",".join(line)
            print header
        else:
            print "{},{}".format(my_val, ",".join(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('data', 'r', newline='') as f,  open('data_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # read headers
    headers = next(reader)
    # insert new column name
    headers.insert(0,"NewCol")

    w = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',')
    # write headers
    w.writerow(headers)

    for line in f:
        if ',' not in line:
            newcolumn = line.strip()
        else:
            line = newcolumn + ',' + line.strip()
            line = line.split(',')
            w.writerow(line)

data_out.csv

NewCol,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
Foo,value1,value2,value3,value4
Foo,value1,value2,value3,value4
Bar,value1,value2,value3,value4
Bar,value1,value2,value3,value4
```